# Split Django project in several servers

Tags: django, split

May I split a Django project in different servers? I mean: I create a project (startproject) and, inside it, I create 2 apps (startapp). Is it possible that each app lives in a different server? Or do I need one Django project per app?

**UPDATE: I will explain a bit more**

I'm going to create a web based application aimed to 2 different types of users:

- Consumers
- Creators.

So, the application has 2 different parts:

- A simple web client, to access some content (for consumers)
- A wizard (for creators), that guides the user to upload and edit the content that will be consumed by the first kind of clients.

There will be more consumers than creators. And one important thing is the consumer part will be public (anyone can access the content), but the creator part will require authentication.

As there are way more consumers than creators, it makes sense (for me) split the app in 2 parts (different servers for each apps) and put more resources in the consumer app (heavy load, a lot of traffic) than in the creator app (less users, less traffic)

I know: I'm basically defining Youtube.

Comment: What do you mean with "the app lives on a different server"? Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not to my knowledge - no.  I think the problem you are trying to solve is not really a Django issue.  You are trying to put a customer facing and associate facing application on two different networks and you want as much isolation as possible.  Possibly network separation or at least different VLANs / access control etc.,

My suggestion is that you create them as separate projects and separate apps in Django.

Comment: Ok, I overthought this. You're just right. Many thanks!